# GreatMaps (GMap.net) Offline Files...To Download?

Tags: winforms, gmap.net

I'm trying to create a map viewer for an existing C# WinForms application. I've installed and hooked up the GreatMaps (GMap.net) controls no problem and that's all working fine. The quirk in this is that it needs to work offline (as it's an application that gets used by users who aren't always in locations where there's a mobile signal).

The offline cache mode works fine for GMap but, we've got to build the cache beforehand which we can do but, as we need the whole of the UK, will be a pain (especially as we have to go down to street level).

Does anybody know if there any existing cache files that we can download and use? I've looked at downloading OSM files but haven't got the faintest idea how to use them, convert them (into the gmdb format that GMap seems to use).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out VectorTileRenderer (https://github.com/AliFlux/VectorTileRenderer) which has a demo for Gmap.net. All you need is an MBTiles file which you can download for free at OpenMapTiles.org (https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/europe/british-isles/)

Comment: Nice. This might just do the job (and save me losing any more hair trying to get it to work) =:)