# How can I add an offline map in a Windows forms application (C# .NET 8)?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I use GMap.NET in the application I developed on a Windows form application. It works fine, but how can I make it work in an environment without internet?

**(First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English, English is not my native language.)**

I am trying to develop a simple application on Windows form application (C# .NET 8.0). I apologize for my inexperience as I am new to this field.

Below is the code of my application.

```
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace harita_3_offline
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Map Config */
            //gMapControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
            gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"D:\\cache\\turkey.mbtiles";
            gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
            gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
            gMapControl1.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(37.87425528270441, 32.493648881146235);
          
            gMapControl1.MinZoom = 1;
            gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 20;
            gMapControl1.Zoom = 15;

            gMapControl1.ShowCenter = false;
            /* ./Map Config */
        }
    }
}
```

I have a map object named `gMapControl1`. There are a few customizations in my code.

My problem is, The map works fine when connected to the internet. But when I disconnect the internet, the map is corrupted and does not work.

[image: map screen]

I downloaded a ".mbtiles" file from the internet. This is how I added it to my application.

```
gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"D:\\cache\\turkey.mbtiles";
```

But this didn't solve my problem. I did research on the internet. It says it can show the cached map. But what I want is to show the map of the entire country I downloaded. How can I do that?

I tried some solutions below but none of them worked :(

> [GreatMaps (GMap.net) Offline Files...To Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913246/greatmaps-gmap-net-offline-files-to-download)
> I couldn't run the shared github application because it was old.

> [GMap .net offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711953/gmap-net-offline) Likewise, I could not manage to run it because the codes shared on github were too old.

Comment: The ZOOM values are not in range.  If found the mbtitles specification which may help solve issue : https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md.  It may be the cache location is on the internet.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/reference/unity/class/google/maps/cache-options

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your answer. However, since I am new to these issues, I cannot say that I fully understand your answer. But I learned something. I think C# uses sqlite for the map cache, but I'm trying to add the ".mbtiles" file to the cache. Now I'm looking for how to convert the ".mbtiles" file to "sqlite" format.

Comment: Use a file explorer and see if you can access the cache file : gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"D:\\cache\\turkey.mbtiles";   This does not make sense.  Try (only one slash) : gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"D:\cache\turkey.mbtiles";

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer. However, adding "\" (only one slash) did not work.

Comment: Use a File Explorer and see if you can find the file on the D drive.

Comment: @jdweng yes I found. I don't think the problem is with the file path. I think the problem is that the .MBTiles file is not suitable for cache.

Comment: Are you getting same error? I do not use SQLite a  lot.  Maybe try the debugging hints are following https://sqlite.org/docs.html